# gluLookAt is not working properly

Tags: java, opengl, graphics

I'm trying to make the camera follow an object. Here's a dummy of my `Camera` class:

```
public void setView(GL2 gl){
    double[] myPos = MyObject.getCoords();
    double[] myTarget = MyObject.getTarget();
    double myRotation = MyObject.getRotation(); 

    double viewX = myPos[0]+(myTarget[0]*0.1);
    double viewZ = myPos[2]+(myTarget[1]*0.1);
    double camHeight = Terrain.altitude(myPos[0],myPos[2]) + 0.3;
    GLU glu = new GLU();
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);  
    gl.glLoadIdentity();    

    gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_LIGHT1);        
    //Look at where the object is looking from behind the object
    glu.gluPerspective(100, aspect, 0.1, 20); 
    System.out.println("Teapot pos" + myPos[0] + myPos[2]);
    System.out.println("Eye pos" + (myPos[0]-myTarget[0]) + (myPos[2]-myTarget[1]));
    glu.gluLookAt(-(myPos[0]-myTarget[0]),-camHeight,-(myPos[2]-myTarget[1]), viewX, camHeight, viewZ, 0, 1, 0);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();      
    gl.glPopMatrix();
}
```

And here is the dummy code in my `MyObject` class:

```
public static void draw(GL2 gl) {

    GLUT glut = new GLUT();

    gl.glPushMatrix();
    //Draw a teapot
    gl.glTranslated(-coords[0],-coords[1], -coords[2]);
    gl.glRotated(-Math.toDegrees(rotation),0,1,0);      
    glut.glutSolidTeapot(0.1);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
}
```

To make `MyObject` move, the codes are like this in `MyObject` class:

```
// move object
public void translate(double displacement) {
    coords[0] += displacement*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation));
    coords[2] += displacement*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation));
    coords[1] = Terrain.altitude(coords[0], coords[2]);
}

// Rotate camera by degrees
// Target is the vector where MyObject is facing
public void rotate(double rot) {
    rotation += rot;
    target[0] = -Math.sin(Math.toDegrees(rotation));
    target[1] = -Math.cos(Math.toDegrees(rotation));
}
```

Whenever I print the coordinates without rotating everything seems working fine. After the rotation it is not working properly. For some reason, the camera and the object are moving in different directions. The rotation is kind of weird as well because sometimes I cannot see the teapot. Can anyone help me out with this problem?

Comment: Afaik, `Math.sin` takes radians instead of degrees.